# Verify correct Google Analytics setup by inspecting the tracker object in a single page app

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application

I have a single page app that uses Google Analytics. The account key and domain change per-environment because the tracking is meant to be segmented by environment so the setup is somewhat involved.

I would like to be able to verify that the `_gaq` object has my account key as expected and that is has the domain name set as expected. When I run the code google provides to get the account key, I only get back `A-XXXXX-X`.

```
_gaq.push(function() {
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
  console.log(pageTracker._getAccount()) // Logs UA-XXXXX-X, not my actual number
});
```

What is the right way to verify the correct configuration of the _gaq object?

Comment: The problem might be related to the difference between the new universal method https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced my account is using and this tracking code, but the question of how to validate that it's misconfigured I am still interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify correct configuration by running these commands in console:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  console.log( tracker.get('trackingId') )
  console.log( tracker.get('cookieDomain') )
});
```

This will log out the tracking ID and domain google is expecting you to track against. If the configuration is set up correctly, these values will be what you have configured.